# Consecutive Substring in Python

Tags: python, string, substring

I need to find count of substring like 'ACA' in a string like ACACA. I tried `count(str)` method but it gave me only 1 instead of 2. How can I find actual number of occurrences in python on these strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for the `count` [method of strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) says:

> Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in the range [start, end].

Your substrings overlapped, which is why the `count` method did not do what you wanted. You can use the `find` method's optional parameter to start at a place other than the string's start to find your count:

```
string = 'ACACA'
substr = 'ACA'

substr_count = 0
start = 0
while True:
    loc = string.find(substr, start)
    if loc == -1:
        break
    substr_count += 1
    start = loc + 1
```

This routine's loop count is the same as the number of occurrences of your sub-string in the string. You could use a simpler routine that checks each location of your string to see if the sub-string is at that location, but that take more loops and would be slower.

Comment: Thank you really so much. I used your code and additionnaly I developed mine thanks to you!